# Tensorflow equivalent to torch's expand call?

Tags: tensorflow, expand

I need to repeat a tensor many times along a singleton dimension without allocating more memory, e.g. as in [torch's expand call](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#expandingreplicatingsqueezing-tensors).  Is there a recipe for doing this in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow)?

Comment: Broadcasting obviates the need for this -- in TF/numpy `[1, 1, 1]+2` will implicitly "expand" 2 to get `[3, 3, 3]`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov How about tf.tile? I am not sure tile won't allocating more memory tough.

Comment: Yes, that allocates memory. It's like `numpy.tile`. My theory is that `numpy` doesn't have `expand` because you don't need when you have broadcasting, so we don't need it in TensorFlow either

Comment: I think you need to look at `tf.broadcast_to`

Answer (score 0):

As @YaroslavBulatov says, broadcasting takes care of any needed calls to expand implicitly.